# Past tense or present tense to describe something that 'happened in the past' but is still true?

Tags: grammar, tenses, backshifting

For example:

"Last week, I found out that NASA stands for 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration.'"

or

"Last week, I found out that NASA stood for 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration.'"