# Choice between past tense and present tense?

Tags: tenses

Todd is asking Dan about his concept of slow travel. The following passage is part of  Dan's reply.

> Yeah, I mean especially maybe because I'm a blogger, we're always
>   seeking to define things in unique ways. And there’s a lot of terms
>   out there. There’s expat; people that have left their native country.
>   There’s backpacker, which is someone who tries to keep their cost very
>   low and they’re continually moving from place to place. There’s flash
>   packer, which is a term that means you still have income from
>   somewhere and you have more tech and toys, and you stay at maybe nicer
>   hotels.
>
> **But what I did** was always a little bit different, which is I **would go**
>   and get long term leases or medium term leases at apartments. So **I
>   would go** and get a house or an apartment in a place for anywhere from
>   one to six months, and enjoy what it feels like to actually live
>   somewhere.And that to me is so exciting, you know. Although the
>   sights and everything are cool, and hanging out with tourists can be
>   fun, I much prefer to go down to the local café, open up my laptop,
>   talk to the people that are working there, and really get a sense for
>   what it’s like to live in a city. (From
>   http://www.elllo.org/english/1301/T1325-Dan-Slowtravel.htm)

At first the speaker is using the present tense (the entire first paragraph). Then he suddenly starts using the past tense(did, would go, would go), and then returns to the present tense again.

The speaker could well have said the following instead to keep the tense consistency.

> But what I **do** is always a little bit different, which is I **go** and
>   get long term leases or medium term leases at apartments. So I **go**
>   and get a house or an apartment in a place for anywhere from one to
>   six months, and enjoy what it feels like to actually live somewhere.

I want to know why the speaker chooses the past tense over the present tense in the beginning of the second paragraph.  Thanks for the comments and the answer which help me clarify my question.

Comment: One assumes that 'what it feels like to actually live somewhere' has changed little over the time-span between the historical setting (the time / days when 'I would go and get a house or an apartment ... ') and the time of writing. The switch _is_ a little jarring – I'd have a new paragraph for 'And that to me is so exciting ... '.

Comment: In fact, I think that [He didn't know where New Jersey was](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/he-didnt-know-where-new-jersey-was);  [“I didn't know you liked her” or “I didn't know you like her”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149120/i-didnt-know-you-liked-her-or-i-didnt-know-you-like-her/149167#149167); and [Past tense or present tense to describe something that 'happened in the past' but is still true](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150709/past-tense-or-present-tense-to-describe-something-that-happened-in-the-past-bu) could best be amalgamated.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I think I am not particularly concerned about would enjoy or enjoy.  I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 2):

So I **would go and get** a house or an apartment in a place for anywhere from one to six months, and **(would) enjoy** what it feels like to actually live somewhere.

that's how I understand it, but it could be wrong.

Comment: It's not wrong - as you say the *would* carries over so we understand *would enjoy*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, wtdark. I don't see how this really helps; 'and _would_ enjoy what it felt like' is the expanded version of the alternative. Why _feels_ (and then _is_; _are_; _can be_ ...) rather than _felt_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think the OP realises that *would* + present refers to a habitual action the past, or the question would relate to *would go* as well as *... enjoy*, so I think the answer is spot on.

Comment: +1 I agree with this, but would add more to the assumed elision: *I **would go and** get . . .and [I would go and] enjoy.* As matter of preference, I would actually write *go and enjoy* rather than just *enjoy*. (Or I would not use *go and* in the first part of the sentence at all.)

Comment: @Minty There's no argument about 'would' having been omitted. But 'would go and enjoy what it feels like' and  'would go and enjoy what it felt like' remain possibilities. This question is about "[the use of the p]ast tense or present tense to describe something that 'happened in the past' but is still true[]", and has been covered before.