# Which correct - “comments are or comments were”

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatically correct?

It’s about youtube comments. Should I say the comments are funny or the comments were funny?

Or the comments on twitter are funny or comments were funny?

Thanks

Comment: Watching the YouTube you may say, 'The comments are funny.' ...were funny refers to the past watching.

Comment: Thanks. How about on twitter? Should I say the comments are funny?

Comment: Take care that 'The comments are funny' may not be considered a pleasing comment by many, because the word 'funny' can have negative connotations. Depending upon situations, people use phrases like: Interesting comments, good observations, good message, points worth learning etc. You may need to customize according to situation.

Comment: Is the anwer at [Past tense or present tense to describe something that happened in the past but is still true?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150709/past-tense-or-present-tense-to-describe-something-that-happened-in-the-past-bu) adequate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The comments presumably never get deleted. So the tense really refers to whether you still find them funny.

If you'd still find them funny reading them today "the comments are funny".